# Angular2 testing form: submit method not called

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular

Having this component

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'something',
    templateUrl: 'something.html',
    providers: [],
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: []
})
export class Something {

    constructor() { }

    save(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
}
```

with this template (something.html)

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value)">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input id="title" type="text" ngControl="title" />

    <label for="primaryImage">Primary Image</label>
    <input id="primaryImage" type="text" ngControl="primaryImage" />

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

and this test

```
it('should call save method after clicking a Save button', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    return tcb.createAsync(Something).then((fixture) => {
        spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'save');
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
        compiled.querySelector('#title').value = 'testTitle';
        compiled.querySelector('#primaryImage').value = 'tabc.png';                   
        compiled.querySelector('button').click();
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.save).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            title: 'testTitle',
            primaryImage: 'abc.png'
        });
    });
}));
```

The test fails, the save method hasn't been called on the spy.
However, when I manually try it in browser, if works, alert is shown.
The test fails too when instead of button.click I do form.submit.

When I use `(click)="save(myForm.value)"` on the button instead of `ngSubmit` on the form, test still fails, but the reason is different. Save method on the spy has been called in this case, but the data passed to it is `{}`.

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add to Juanmi's answer for the test to be fully complete, the event have to be triggered by clicking on the button, because for example, if the button is moved out of the  tag, the application would fail, but the test would still pass.

I have managed to go around the problem above, by calling the 'click()' method of the native element (not the debug element). See the code below. Note that in my code below, i'm using the ReactiveForms syntax, but it shouldn't make a difference for the test.

```
<form [formGroup]="sampleForm" (submit)="submit($event)">
    <input id="sampleBtn" type="submit" class="btn-default btn btn-primary" value="Click Me">
</form>
```

And in my spec.ts file

```
spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'submit');
let loginBtn: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#sampleBtn'));
loginBtn.nativeElement.click();
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(fixture.componentInstance.submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This click() on the button would, in turn, trigger the (submit) handler function. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: My tests look different now, so I can't test, but your answer makes sense to me. Accepting.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case it can help someone:

I have been able to trigger the submit event in the form using the By selector and triggerHandle

```
let form = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form'));
form.triggerEventHandler('submit', null);
fixture.detectChanges();
// your component function should have been called
```

If you try to trigger the click in the button the event it doesn't seem to trigger the ngSubmit. And if you try to do .submit on the form it will not be captured by angular and will refresh the page.

Comment: I found this with -1 points, and yet it's the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `fixture.detectChanges();` right before click.